# The function processes only the last pattern sought. What is wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
/**
 * Quick Links for ACF
 */
function replace_text($content) {
    $quick_links = get_field('quick_links', 'option');
    if($quick_links && is_singular('post')) {
        foreach($quick_links as $item) {
            $word = $item['word_quick_links'];
            $link = $item['link_quick_links'];
            $preg_replace = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/', '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $word . '</a>', $content, 1);
        }
        return $preg_replace;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text', 20 );
```

In the preg_replace() function, the last argument is limit - the maximum possible number of replacements of each template for each subject line. By default it is equal to -1 (without restrictions).

What is my mistake, why does the function process only one last sought-for template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner loop which replaces the text in the content, you always start off with the original text (`$content`) and return a new string (`$preg_replace`)...

```
    $preg_replace = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/', '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $word . '</a>', $content, 1);
```

You should instead put the result back into the original content so that the next loop will add to the replacements rather than get a new string (so put the new value back into `$content`)...

```
    $content = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/', 
        '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $word . '</a>',
        $content, 1);
```

and then return this value (you could always return `$content`...

```
    return $content;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You've helped out a lot.
Thank you for the detailed explanation.